# Extending BaseActivity for a class which already extends from third party library

Tags: java, android

I have a MainActivity which is inherited from a third party library as:

```
public class MainActivity extends ParallaxViewPagerBaseActivity {
}
```

This works fine, but recently I added a `BaseActivity()` class to move all the common functionality to all the current classes i have. But I don't have any idea how to extend `MainActivity` from `BaseActivity` which is already extending a
third party library.

PS: This is my first android project, hence not sure if this query itself is lame.

Comment: All the others activities you want to extend `BaseActivity` also extend from `ParallaxViewPagerBaseActivity` too? If true, just let `BaseActivity` extend `ParallaxViewPagerBaseActivity` or vice versa. If false, then hard luck.

Comment: @Minhtdh, actually only MainActivity needs to extend ParallaxViewPagerBaseActivity. :(  Another approach, I could think of is to modify the 3rd party library code and extend it there from BaseActivity.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't support multiple inheritance. So you can't extend more than one base classes. Instead make a function in the activity you want to extend and create an object for the class.  Then using the object and function make up with the process you need.